# Outward pointing unit normal associated with a norm function

Tags: differential-geometry

Consider a norm $\| \cdot\|:  \Bbb R^n\rightarrow \Bbb R$ (in general not an euclidean norm) and the associated unit sphere $B=\{x\in \Bbb R^n | \|x\|=1\}$. Which are the conditions for the function $\|\cdot\|$ that ensure the existence of the outward pointing unit normal for every $x_0\in B$? Is there an explicit form for the normal vector trough the use of the function $\|\cdot\|$? What the normal vector to the surface $B$?
For example if $\|\cdot\|$ is the euclidean norm then the normal vector to the sphere is $\eta=\frac {x}{\|x\|}.$

Comment: That’s certainly not a unit normal! You are also confusing ball with sphere. Should the word differentiable enter?

Comment: are there referee?

Comment: Just standard multivariable calculus.

Comment: the normal vector depends by geometry of $B$ that in general is not the standard sphere

Comment: In $\Bbb R^2$ endowed with the norm $\|(x,y)\| = \max\{|x|,|y|\}$, the unit sphere is a square, and does not admit a unit normal vector on its corner. Elsewhere, the unit normal is just $(\pm 1,0)$ and $(0,\pm 1)$ depending on which side of the square you are. It follows that there is clearly no "smooth" relation between $\frac{(x,y)}{\|(x,y)\|}$ and the unit normal. But it is worth noting that the unit normal is the gradient of the distance function from the square, and this can be generalised